# How do I set basic authentication on .NET web service on install?

Tags: c#, web-services

Is it possible to set a web service to use Basic authentication during install or dynamically when the web service is started? I am currently using Visual Studio to create and MSI to install the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a Web Service to accept Basic authentication depends not only on your projects configuration but also on your hosting environment.

IIS:
Basic Auth against primary AD? Let IIS solve this:

- Turn basic auth on in IIS settings.

Basic Auth against custom LDAP? Let ASP.Net solve this.

- Turn auth off in IIS settings,
- Configure an LDAP HttpModule in your web.config
- [optional] Add Principle&Identity providers (code) to your WCF runtime (config).

So, looking at this; I would advise for your MSI to apply the appropriate settings to IIS and 'adjust/modify' the 'web.config' file during/after installation.

Hope this helps,